# Am I being ghosted by a recruiter?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, hiring-process, internship, software-engineering

Global Software Company reached me from LinkedIn for 6 month Java Internship and I am accepted.

She said to me - I am waiting for more details (new office in Turkey, terms on Turkey and dates). We talked on 07.02.2024 and still no answer or no meeting.

When I checked the websites (such as glassdoor) many people who have previously interviewed with the company are ghosted in the final section.

I don't know too much SE recruitment process but my first intern interview process resulted in 4 day and started next week. Is this normal process timeline or am I worrying too much?

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/karadennison/2023/11/27/how-ghost-job-postings-are-creating-a-false-sense-of-hope/ and https://www.forbes.com/sites/robinryan/2022/11/30/be-careful-of-employers-posting-ghost-jobs/

Comment: 5 days is not a long time for a job application. The relevant person might be busy or on vacation. Give them a little time.

Comment: I once applied to a company on a Friday evening, we then meet for an interview while having breakfast together in a café on Sunday morning and I signed the contract Monday evening. But that was truly an exception. In general, looking back at my career, most interview processes took between a month and six weeks from applying to signing the contract.

Answer (score 10):

> Is this normal process timeline or am I worrying too much?

There is no "normal processing time". Sometimes decisions are made in days and sometimes it may take months. Many factors related to priorities and budgeting come into play which can change very fast.

Do not worry about whether the recruiter is ghosting you are not. If they have not reached out to you, they do not need you at least for now.  Move on to find the next opportunity.

Comment: this. You do not stop looking for your job until you have started your job. To stop because you think you landed one is a dangerous mistake. Since you aren't going to "only keep looking for a job if this recruiter has ghosted me", you're going to keep looking no matter what, you no longer need to know urgently if they have ghosted you or not. You'll know eventually but it's not useful information right now.

Answer (score 4):

In the end it is important to understand that recruiters, at their core, are salesmen.  They have very different personalities then the engineers they seek to place and often times are not capable of understanding the technology we work with.

In this case, it may have been a new contract company attempting to build its databases of resumes.  This is typically done by listing false job openings and posting them to the message boards.

It may also have been a recruiter was contacted by a client for a staffing need for a new project, but then something happened.  Either the client didn't get the project (so no longer a staffing need) or the relationship between the recruiter and client had ended.

There is no way to tell and you just have to move on and accept that "rejection" is part of life.  In this case, I don't think it was rejection as much as it was no longer a need.